# Append vector as a data frame column according to another column in the data frame

Tags: r

I have a dataframe.

```
c1 <- c(3,6,8,2,7)
c2 <- c("S", "", "S", "", "")
df <- data.frame(c1, c2)
```

I also have a vector

```
vec <- c(200, 210)
```

I want to add the values from the vector into a new column in the data frame where there are S values. In rows where no S values are present I just want blank spaces in the new column. The desired output is shown below.

```
#Output
#   c1 c2 new_column
#1  3  S      200
#2  6    
#3  8  S      210
#4  2    
#5  7
```

For my actual data there may be hundreds of rows, many with S values. How can I append this vector in this manner?

Comment: You can't have blanks in a numeric column, but you can do `df$new_column[df$c2 == 'S'] <- vec` which will fill with `NA` instead of blanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Columns in a data frame must have all items the same class. Your `vec` is class `numeric`, but a blank `""` is class `character`. You can't mix those in the same column. Missing values `NA` are a good workaround. I would suggest using `NA` values instead of blanks in your numeric column as in `option_1` below. However, if you really want blanks we can use a `character` class column as in `option_2` below, with the drawback that you won't be able to do math with your numbers because we are treating them as `character` class not `numeric` class to mix them with empty strings `""`.

```
df$option_1[df$c2 != ""] = vec

df$option_2 = ""
df$option_2[df$c2 != ""] = vec

df
#   c1 c2 option_1 option_2
# 1  3  S      200      200
# 2  6          NA         
# 3  8  S      210      210
# 4  2          NA         
# 5  7          NA
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to filter the initial data frame to entries with an S value, appending the vector, and then joining with the original. The code might be something like:

```
s_value_df <- df %>% dplyr::filter(c2 == "S")
s_value_df$new_column <- vec
final_df <- dplyr::left_join(df, s_value_df)
```

This will put NAs where you just have empty strings though so you can replace them after

Comment: You can do this all in one pipeline avoiding the temporary data frame, `df %>% filter(c2 != "") %>% mutate(new_column = vec) %>% left_join(x = .)`. But it does rely on the assumption that `c1` doesn't have duplicate values - it'd be safer with a proper ID column that is known to be unique.